# Пароль для доступа к WPF приложению

Tags: wpf, авторизация, защита, пароль, аутентификация

Как для приложения, написанного на WPF, задать пароль доступа? Когда первый раз открываешь приложение, то вводишь новый пароль, при последующих входах вводишь уже этот пароль. Это должно быть реализовано без использования БД.

Comment: Где хранить пароль?

Comment: где угодно, может быть в ресурсах.

Comment: Главное не в базе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Положите свойство `Password` типа `string` [в application settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx), а также свойство `IsPasswordSet` типа `bool` (с начальным значением `false`). Обязательно кладите в user scope, не в application scope!

Теперь вы можете использовать код наподобие такого:

```
if (!Properties.Settings.Default.IsPasswordSet)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Set password: ");
    Properties.Settings.Default.Password = Console.ReadLine();
    Properties.Settings.Default.IsPasswordSet = true;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter password: ");
    var password = Console.ReadLine();
    if (password != Properties.Settings.Default.Password)
        Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

Это решение, однако, хранит пароль в открытом виде. Если вы хотите что-то более надёжное, считайте (криптографический!) хэш от пароля и храните его, при проверке берите хэш от ввода и сравнивайте.

---

Вы можете усилить защиту пароля, если зашифруете вашу конфигурацию, как указано [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx#Anchor_2).

Однако решения, при которых проверка пароля происходит на системе, находящейся под контролем пользователя, **принципиально небезопасны**. Злонамеренный пользователь может подменить данные, в которых вы храните пароль, на свои. Ну и любую программу, работающую под контролем пользователя, можно взломать. Поэтому **не используйте** это решение, если от силы парольной защиты зависит безопасность или открывается доступ к важной информации.

Comment: У меня есть команда **SetPassCommand**. Не пойму как по нажатии на кнопку "Задать" (при первом входе) передать в **CommandParameter** сразу два значения (у меня на форме нужно задать пароль и подтверждение пароля), чтобы сравнить их.

Comment: @endovitskiiy: Создайте класс с двумя полями, и упакуйте оба значения в него? И его же и передавайте.

Comment: А как упаковать сразу два поля, ведь для PasswordBox нельзя задать Binding

Comment: Сделал так: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108044/how-to-pass-parameters-to-command-using-multibinding

Comment: @endovitskiiy: Ага, Tuple — тоже хороший вариант.